# How to call my PDO variable inside a class method?

Tags: php, t-sql, pdo

I have the following class:

```
<?php

    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-content/themes/quest/wahoo/common.php');


    class TestingClass
    {
        private function InsertUser()
        {
            $query = "EXEC dbo.InsertUser   @Title = @sTitle, -- varchar(50)
                                        @FirstName = @sFirstName, -- varchar(100)
                                        @MiddleName = @sMiddleName, -- varchar(100)
                                        @LastName = @sLastName, -- varchar(100)
                                        @Gender = @sGender, -- varchar(20)
                                        @DOB = @sDOB, -- datetime
                                        @Email = @sEmail, -- varchar(200)
                                        @Phone = @sPhone, -- varchar(50)
                                        @Mobile = @sMobile, -- varchar(50)
                                        @HomeAddress = @sHomeAddress, -- varchar(100)
                                        @HomePostCode = @sHomePostCode, -- varchar(10)
                                        @HomeSuburb = @sHomeSuburb, -- varchar(50)
                                        @HomeState = @sHomeState, -- varchar(20)
                                        @HomeCountry = @sHomeCountry, -- varchar(200)
                                        @BrowserDetails = @sBrowserDetails, -- varchar(500)
                                        @IsActive = @sIsActive, -- bit
                                        @Password = @sPassword, -- varchar(500)
                                        @Salt = @sSalt, -- varchar(50)
                                        @LastLogin = GETDATE(), -- datetime
                                        @CompanyID = @sCompanyId, -- int
                                        @Created = GETDATE(), -- datetime
                                        @CreatedBy = user, -- varchar(50)
                                        @LastModified = NULL, -- datetime
                                        @LastModifiedBy = NULL, -- varchar(50)
                                        @UserName = @sUserName, -- varchar(50)
                                        @UserRole = 'user' -- varchar(30)";


            $query_params = array(
                ':username' => $_POST['username']
            );

            try
            {

                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex)
            {
                // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
                // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.
                die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
            }

            // display json encode on the page for AJAX to read
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
    }
?>
```

Which with this line:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
```

I'm attempting to use the following PDO variable from my common file:

```
$db = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server = tcp:$host; Database = $dbname", "$username", "$password");
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

I can do this just fine outside of a class, but once I'm inside a class method and try to use $db I'm being told that the variable is undefined. Is there a way I can still do this without having to resort to using a global variable (especially since I want to move my common file outside of wwwroot)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass your variable to your class:

```
class TestClass {
    private $db = null;
    public function __construct($db){
         $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function executeSomething(){
          // you can now use $this->db as your PDO object
          // $db = $this->db;
          // $stmt = $db->prepare('sql code');
    }
}

$db = new PDO('...');

$instance = new TestClass($db);
$instance->executeSomething();
```

Comment: Close, however I receive the error: 

Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string in C:\DWASFiles\Sites\junglegym\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\qcore\qcore_waitress.php on line 38

Comment: Please provide some code, since I tested this and it worked. Fill in a connection string in the PDO(''), and try a query like $db = $this->db;
         $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tablename');
        $stmt->execute();
        var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());